# django: get HTML form value in view.py failed with empty <QueryDict: {}> and None value

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django and follow the djangogirls tutorial. With a few modifications, I am trying to get the value from the form text field and print it in view.py and then display this value again in another "result" field in the html page.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>num_1:</label>
            <input type = "text" name="num_1" value = "1" placeholder="Enter value">
        </div>
        <div>
           <label>num_2:</label>
            <input type = "text" name="num_2" value = "2" placeholder="Enter value">
        </div>
    </form>

        <div>
            <label>result:</label>
            {{ result }}
        </div>
    <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

view.py:

```
def post_list(request):
    # posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
    num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
    result = int(num1)+int(num2)
    print(request.POST)
    print("num1 ", num1)
    # return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'result': result})
```

when I activate the local server, I got:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
<QueryDict: {}>
num1  None
```

Comment: How are you getting into `post_list` i don't see any call. Can you you add code for it

Comment: This looks like somewhere in your code you call post_list(...) upon starting runserver. That means it is not called by a POST request  but internally and therefore request contains no POST data. Did you setup a urlpatten? Another hint: your html form has no submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `method="post"` and [{% csrf_token %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/) for your form. For example:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <label>num_1:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_1" value="1" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>num_2:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_2" value="2" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your `views.py`:

```
def post_list(request):
    result = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
        num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
        print(request.POST)
        print(result)

    context = {
        'result': result
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

Here is frontend:

[image]

And terminal:

[image]

Comment: thank you it works. I am wondering how to prevent the page reloading after clicking submit. I want the page directly show the result without refresh. I tried adding "<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>" and the page did not refresh but also the result also did not refresh with the actual result value only terminal shows it.

Comment: BTW,  what's {% csrf_token %} used for?

Comment: @Jack: Hi Jack, the value need load to update new value. But if you don't want load entire page, you can use AJAX or websocket to update realtime data.
{% csrf_token %} use for defense against CSRF attacks. You can see more at here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: can u provide an example? does it mean i have to give up using django framwork?

Comment: @Jack: You can follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TXtsTutoQQ or search google keyword `AJAX in Django`. It's complicated to explain in only this comment.

Comment: it's a long video. what is the time when talking about the updating realtime data without reload page.

Comment: @Jack: Ok, we can create a chat room and discuss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240522/discussion-between-jack-and-nguyn-v-thien).

Comment: I have tried your approach. unfortunately, it's not working. I guess there are some error in the code. To make life easier, could you kindly send me the child html,post_list.html and the view.py? So I can compare to find where is wrong

Comment: @Jack: Ok, I'll share you my old project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15UjTotHwEB2uJOPparL6V3I_aWAe2ZZY/view?usp=sharing. If you have any question you can contact me via skype or gmail.

Comment: thanks a lot. your project is too complext to new learner like me however. The easiest approach would be showing me the child html,post_list.html and the view.py concerning the simple scenario in this post? So I can compare to find where is wrong.

Comment: I opened a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541667/django-html-form-submit-without-jumping-into-new-page-or-refreshing-reloading