# django: html form submit without jumping into new page or refreshing/reloading

Tags: html, django, ajax, forms, iframe

I am new to django and html. below is my first test web page of a simple online calculator.

I found a problem that when clicking the "submit" button, it tends to jump to a new web page or a new web tab. this is not what I want.  Once the user input the data and click "submit" button, I want the "result" field on the page directly show the result (i.e. partially update only this field) without refresh/jump to the new page. Also I want the user input data kept in the same page after clicking "submit".

I saw there might be several different ways to do this work, iframe/AJAX. Since I am new, what is the really simplest way to achieve this goal? BTW, I dont write javascripts.

html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <label>num_1:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_1" value="1" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>num_2:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_2" value="2" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

view.py

```
def post_list(request):
    result = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
        num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
        print(request.POST)
        print(result)

    context = {
        'result': result
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of using Ajax, which I hope will be useful to you.

first you need change `post_list` view:

## view

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def post_list(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
      num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
      result = int(num1) + int(num2)

      return JsonResponse({"result":result})

   else:
      return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context={"result":0})
```

I use `JsonResponse` because I just want to get the `result` data in ajax and display it in the html , for `GET` request  render the html file and for `POST` request use JsonResponse  to return a json like context.
And your html file should to be a look like this:

## html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form method="POST" id="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <label>num_1:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_1" value="1" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>num_2:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_2" value="2" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="result" >{{ result }}</div>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(
  $('#post-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "/your_url/",
      data:  serializedData,
      success: function(data){
        $("#result").text(data["result"]);
      }
    });
  })
);
</script>
```

First I added jQuery cdn and then your html file, except that I added attribute `id=post-form` to the form and added `id=result`, then `<script>` tag was  added and jquery function inside the  tag was execute when your form  Submited(detect event by the id `#post-form`).

And get the data(`num_1, num_2`) by serialize method then use Ajax to send `POST` reqeust to the view function(`post_list`), in Ajax you just need to pass `serializedData` and url(also you can use the Django url tag or set it in action form or...), After that we need to send data to the html(means the result data we received from the View).

> in `success` function Ajax you can add html tag to your html file or
> replace the some values,...

In Ajax, you must specify your URL to send the data.
for example if you have this url.py

## urls.py

```
from .views import post_list

urlpatterns = [ 
    path("posts_list/", post_list, name="post_list"),
]
```

In ajax you can add an address like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "/posts_list/",
      ....
```

Or

```
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "{% url 'post_list' %}",
      ....
```

And if you have app_name in urls.py you can added  `url: "{% url 'app_name:post_list' %}",`

Comment: thank you for your help. when I run it based on your code, the page will turn into a new page showing only {"result": 3}. How to display the result value straightforward above the 'submit' button?

Comment: Make sure you type everything correctly inside the tag script, because one, or ; It can cause such a thing!

Comment: I have copied again and ensure it's exactly same as yours.  now the result field is always "0" without any change, after clicking "submit" button.

Comment: do i have to make some custom change in the <script> </script>?

Comment: You just have to change the URL(url: "/your_url/",).
Do you receive an error in the terminal when you press the submit button?

Comment: yes, "Not Found: /your_url/". I put <url: "views.post_list",>, seems not working

Comment: No this format does not work! If you have a url like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_url/    you should put / my_url / here (url: "/my_url/",)  or you can use django template url tags like url: "{% url 'my_url' %}",  or if you have app name you can added.

Comment: my case is following: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/  I tried url: "/blog_url/" not working

Comment: I updated the answer with a few structure of URLs that you can use, And for the URL you just sent, something like this url: "/en/django_urls/"  will probably work(If you still get the error, you can see the error inside the terminal and see which part of the URL is missing!)! But I suggest you use the Django url tag template or get_absolute_url

Comment: I followed your suggested url configuration and I get: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
posts_list/ [name='post_list']
The empty path didn’t match any of these.